# Paging on Server side bound (odata endpoint) for Kendo MVC grid not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

[image]

Am using

1) kendo mvc grid (telerik UI for asp.net MVC)on my view (Q1-2015)

2) Consuming the ODATA end point (similar to the article http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client) - consuming asp.net web api (odata)

Controller Code

```
 public ActionResult LoadGrid([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["myAPIKeyCookie"] != null)
        {
            var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["myAPIKeyCookie"].Value;
            using (var context = new MyApiClientContext(cookieValue))
            {
                IQueryable<User> users = context.MyApiContainer.Users;// did a watch - users contains data.
                var result = users.ToDataSourceResult(request);// throws an error here - the request url is appended with $count e.g. https://myurl/odata/users()?$count - Shouldnt the toDataSourceResult method add the pagesize as count here automatically?
                return Json(result);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
        return Json(null);
    }
```

My View

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<User>() 
          .Name("GridAjax")
          .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
              .Read(readFrom => readFrom.Action("LoadGrid", "Users"))
              .Model(m => m.Id(model => model.Id))
              .PageSize(5)
    )

          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(u => u.Id).Visible(false);
              columns.Bound(u => u.DisplayName);
              columns.Bound(u => u.Email);
              columns.Bound(u => u.ManagerName);

          })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Editable(e => e.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    )
```

Am encountering an error on the line  "users.ToDataSourceResult". Exception below

{"Message":"The OData path is invalid.","ExceptionMessage":"Invalid action detected. '$count' is not an action that can bind to 'Collection([MyApi.Domain.Entities.User Nullable=False])'.","ExceptionType":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException",
"StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.ParseAtEntityCollection(IEdmModel model, ODataPathSegment previous, IEdmType previousEdmType, String segment)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.DefaultODataPathHandler.Parse(IEdmModel model, 
String odataPath)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)"}

Attached is the screen shot of my watch that shows the url with an empty count hence the conversion error - but shouldnt the page size be appended to the url automatically ? - should I do it manually? Am I missing something here ?I tried with server binding as well- In that case the page size = something doesnt even work - all data is loaded on a 1st page.

Comment: Can someone help me here? I am just wondering how to get this done? Any ideas/inputs will help. thank you!